# How to recognize the JavaScript method(function)

Tags: c#, javascript, visual-studio, .net-2.0

I am writing a Plug-In for VS2008 and I would like to recognize the JavaScript method(function). I have a file - sample.js:`

```
        function test0()
        {
            var i = 0;
            {
                var j = 0;
            }
            var array = { 1: 2, dd: 10, aaa: 3 };
                    return array;
        }

        function test1()
        {
            var ii = "x";
            {
                var xx = "x" + ii;
            }
            return ii;
        }
```

`

How to recognize these methods? Use regular expressions?

Answer (score 4):

Remember that JavaScript functions can be written a few ways. You showed the "C" style function definition, but there are others.

You'll see a lot of "var test2=function(){}".

You'll also see them as members of objects "test3: function(){}".

And you can use "new," but that's not very popular.

And don't forget that many JavaScript functions are anonymous.

For good measure you should handle the immediate invocation pattern:

```
(function () {

  // ...

}());
```

Will the code that you'll see be restricted by some self-imposed rules? If not, you have some parsing to do when you see "function." Especially since "function" could just be a word in some text, and you have a couple different kinds of quotes and a couple kinds of comment styles to unravel to see if it's simply part of a text string or part of a comment.

Comment: Thanks for help. But how to identify internal brackets: "{", "}"
Sample:
function test1()
            {
                var ii = "x";
                {// this is a problem for me
                    var xx = "x" + ii;
                }// this is a problem for me
                return ii;
            }

Comment: Could you edit your original question with a little more detail on your specific question? It's hard to read code in comments.

Comment: The regular expression that solves my problem: "function\\s*?\\([\\w,\\s]*?\\)\\s*?{([^{]|({.*?})*|[^}])*?}". A few more changes and everything should work. Thanks for hints.

Answer (score 0):

Since function  is a reserved keyword, it's safe to assume that as long as the word function is not in quotes it should be a javascript function.

Regex should work. Remember to check if the word is incased in quotes (which would make it a word a string).